# GCP Data Catalog - search columns containing a dot in the column name

Tags: search, google-cloud-platform, metadata, google-data-catalog

Take the public github dataset as an example

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.github_repos.commits`
LIMIT
  2
```

There are column names like

```
difference.old_mode
```

---

via search:

```
column:difference.old_mode
```

will show no results

Answer (score 0):

So, in this case the period isn't actually the column name, its an indication that you're dealing with a complex type (there's a record/struct column  of name `difference`, and within that exists a column named `old_mode`.

Per [search reference](https://cloud.google.com/data-catalog/docs/how-to/search-reference) there's no special syntax for complex schemas documented.

A suggestion might be to leverage a logical `AND` operator like `column:(difference,old_mode)`.  It's not as precise as specifying the column relationship, but it should return the results you're interested in receiving.

Comment: it is not working. the AND operation cannot be the solution because "old_mode" (alone) does not get found